# Is there any way to set parameters of a behavior in an associated model?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a users model with the following association: "Users hasMany Asset". My Assets model utilizes an Upload behavior: "Assets actsas Upload". Is there any way I can set the Upload behavior's parameters from the User model definition? I want to be able to set the upload path directly from the User model and I'm not sure how to set this.

Ideally I can do the following in my User model, but this doesn't work:

```
var $hasMany = Array(
   'Asset' => Array(
       'classname'  => 'Asset',
       'foreignKey' => 'foreign_id',
       'conditions' => Array('Asset.class' => 'User'),
       'dependent'  => true,
       'Upload'     => Array(
           'settings' => Array(
               'filename' => Array('path' => 'src/users')
           )
       )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've reformatted the spacing in your code to make it legible and, as you can see, it's missing some `)` and a `;`. Might that be why it "doesn't work"? If not, what does "this doesn't work" mean?

Comment: sorry, "doesn't work" means that the path does not seem to get set, and the upload fails (attempts to upload to blank path)

Comment: What debugging techniques have you applied so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Options you pass specifying the model relationships are [limited to the type of relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1040/Relationship-Types#!/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together). So you will not be able to pass additional Model configuration this way.

You can set this in the Assets model directly or the Users controller.

Comment: Ah, I've been trying to keep my models so fat and my controllers so skinny that I forgot they existed! Didn't think to do it in the controller. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: This also *sort of* worked (in my Users model beforeSave), but It feels hacky: $this->Asset->Behaviors->Upload->settings['Asset']['filename']['path'] = 'src/users'

Comment: I'm all for fat model, skinny controller philosophy. But *controlling* one model from another beyond relationships seems like a stretch.